# How to request permission in new Android M?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement the new permission model in my app. Here I am requesting for INTERNET permission but getting this error what should I do???

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET);
```

But here Android Studio says **cannot resolve the symbol MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET**. I haven't declared this anywhere and do not know how to do. Can anyone help??

[This is what Android Studio shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZUQh.png)

Comment: thats an int. Have a look at the official docs.

Comment: Ok thanks alot. But what is this variable for, I mean how to initialize it and what does it save??

Comment: Note: you don't have to request the internet permission, since it is a [normal permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/normal-permissions.html) which is granted automatically upon inclusion in your manifest. Only [dangerous permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permission-groups) need to be requested at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Document:

```
 * @param activity The target activity.
 * @param permissions The requested permissions.
 * @param requestCode Application specific request code to match with a result
 *    reported to {@link OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback#onRequestPermissionsResult(
 *    int, String[], int[])}.
 *

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET);
```

You are the one who set (MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET) value, to compare it and do specific action at onRequestPermissionsResult(...) function.

Make sure to implement OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback and override its function onRequestPermissionsResult(...) where you check for requested code if it matches MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET, this is helpful if you will request different permissions, and based on granting each permission you will do specific action in your app, and also in case of refusing the permission by the user you will inform the user with a specific message.